# How do I cascade deletes to multiple tables in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a table with several dependent tables that I want cascade delete. I'm having problems with it cascading too far. Some code will help explain.

```
class Map(Base):
    ....
    #One to many relationship between the Map and Tile.
    #Each Map is made up of many tiles
    tiles = relationship('Tile', lazy='joined', backref='map',
                          cascade="all, delete")

class Tile(Base):
    ....
    #Reference to Map class.
    map_id = Column(Integer,
                ForeignKey('maps.id'),
                nullable=False)

    #Reference to graphics for this tile
    #This is a many to one relationship, each Graphic is used by many Tiles
    graphics_id = Column(Integer,
                     ForeignKey("graphics.id"),
                     nullable=False)

    graphics = relationship("Graphic", uselist=False)

class Graphic(Base):
    ....
    #Nothing special here
```

The problem is that when I delete Map Graphics is also deleted which is not what I want.
I assume this is to do with cascade.

How do I fix this so that deleting the Map class will delete the Tiles but not the Graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing

```
graphics = relationship("Graphic", uselist=False)
```

to

```
graphics = relationship("Graphic", uselist=False, lazy='joined',
        backref=backref('tiles', cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan"))
```

I'm not sure that this is perfect answer but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code (unless some details were omitted) should work as you expect it to**:
Graphics should not be deleted. As can be seen in [relationship](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html?highlight=relationship#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship), the default `cascade` parameter is `save-update, merge`, which should not trigger the `delete` if you were to delete a `Map`.

To test, please create a routine that creates a `Map, a Tile and a Graphic`; then delete a `Map` and check if the Graphic is deleted - I would not expect this to happen. If the conjecture is correct, then your `Graphic` object must be deleted because of some other `relationship`.

I am referring to SA version 0.64, but I believe that the default configuration was not different also in earlier version.